# phonegap zoom in can't slide to other part of zooming

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, canvas

I have add the follow following code to enable zooming in my jquery apps.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes" />
```

Below is my code for in body:

```
<div id="header" data-theme="b" data-role="header">
      <h5>
            Book
      </h5>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
      <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="400" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</div>
```

After I zoom in the canvas picture, I can't slide to see other part of the canvas. Also It seems that the heading "Book" is also zoomed. How can I fixed the problem of sliding and hold the heading remain unchanged without affected by zooming effect?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the default zoom behabiour.

To modify it, first of all change the viewport to

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no" />
```

With this the user can't zoom.

Now you have to handle the zoom for the elements you want using javascript.
You have to detect the `pinch gesture` (there are libraries for that, for example [hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.com/hammer.js/)) with the css3 `transform scale` to make it bigger os smaller according to the gesture. And `drag gesture` with the `transform translate` to move the element

Or you can try [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) too, it has a zoom option which works fine the pinch/zoom/drag

Comment: Beside this library, Is there any easier way to fix the problem?

Comment: I don't think so... You can read an interesting article about fixed positions on different mobile devices, and zoom behaviour. http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/